# reduceByKey in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd similar to following:

```
s = sc.parallelize([(901943132160, {'P1': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C5'}), (901943132160, {'P2': 0.125, 'cust_id': 'C5'}), (901943132160, {'cust_id': 'C5', 'P3': 0.875}), (901943132160, {'P4': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C5'}), (901943132160, {'P5': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C5'}), (901943132160, {'P8': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C5'}), (901943132160, {'cust_id': 'C5', 'P9': 0.875}), (1357209665536, {'P1': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C2'}), (1357209665536, {'P2': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C2'}), (1357209665536, {'cust_id': 'C2', 'P3': 1.0}), (1357209665536, {'P4': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C2'}), (1357209665536, {'P5': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C2'}), (1357209665536, {'P8': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C2'}), (1357209665536, {'cust_id': 'C2', 'P9': 0.75}), (489626271744, {'P1': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C4'}), (489626271744, {'P2': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C4'}), (489626271744, {'cust_id': 'C4', 'P3': 0.5}), (489626271744, {'P4': 0.5, 'cust_id': 'C4'}), (489626271744, {'P5': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C4'}), (489626271744, {'P8': 0.125, 'cust_id': 'C4'}), (489626271744, {'cust_id': 'C4', 'P9': 0.375}), (463856467968, {'P1': 0.08333333333333333, 'cust_id': 'C3'}), (463856467968, {'P2': 0.3333333333333333, 'cust_id': 'C3'}), (463856467968, {'cust_id': 'C3', 'P3': 0.3333333333333333}), (463856467968, {'P4': 0.08333333333333333, 'cust_id': 'C3'}), (463856467968, {'P5': 0.08333333333333333, 'cust_id': 'C3'}), (463856467968, {'P8': 0.3333333333333333, 'cust_id': 'C3'}), (463856467968, {'cust_id': 'C3', 'P9': 0.3333333333333333}), (1305670057984, {'P1': 0.5, 'cust_id': 'C1'}), (1305670057984, {'P2': 0.375, 'cust_id': 'C1'}), (1305670057984, {'cust_id': 'C1', 'P3': 0.0}), (1305670057984, {'P4': 0.0, 'cust_id': 'C1'}), (1305670057984, {'P5': 0.6875, 'cust_id': 'C1'}), (1305670057984, {'P8': 0.0625, 'cust_id': 'C1'}), (1305670057984, {'cust_id': 'C1', 'P9': 0.0625})])
```

I would like to write a reduceByKey operation I am expecting something similar to following:

```
[('C3', {'P8': 0.3333333333333333, 'P1': 0.08333333333333333, 'P9': 0.3333333333333333, 'P2': 0.3333333333333333, 'P3': 0.3333333333333333}), ('C4', {'P9': 0.375, 'P3': 0.5, 'P4': 0.5}), ('C5', {'P9': 0.875, 'P2': 0.125, 'P3': 0.875}), ('C1', {'P1': 0.5,'P2': 0.375,'P5': 0.6875}), ('C2', {'P9': 0.75, 'P3': 1.0, 'P5': 0.0})]
```

What I want to do is , for each product, I will check the score, and return only the one with best three score products. Planning to do this by reduceByKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by doing the following

```
def dictionaryFunc(x):
    d = {}
    for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
        d[x[i]] = x[i+1]
    return d

from operator import add
s.map(lambda x: (x[1]['cust_id'], sorted(x[1].items())[0])).reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: [x[0], dictionaryFunc(x[1])])
```

where 
`x[1]['cust_id']` is taking the value of `cust_id` key of every dictionary
`sorted(x[1].items())[0]` is the first element of the sorted dictionary
`reduceByKey(add)` is adding the second element of the grouped tuples
`dictionaryFunc(x[1])]` is forming dictionaries as required by you